# What is wrong with the method below?

Tags: java

Below is the code for a java method, but it won't compile. I'm using Eclipse and whenever I try to compile my code it says:

> This method must return a result of type `int`.

`a,b,c` have been
 declared as `int`, so the return type is `int`.

```
public static int f(int a, int b, int c) { 
    if ((a < b) && (b < c))
        return a; 
    else    if ((a >= b) && (b >= c))
        return b;
    else    if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c))
        return c; 
}
```

Comment: What happens when none of those conditions are true?

Comment: Use default `else` to handle none of those conditions are true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `if` conditions are not exhaustive. If `a > b` and `b < c`, none of the conditions will match, and your function will not return anything, which is why Eclipse is complaining.

Add a default `return` statement at the end, either without a condition or in an `else` block.

Comment: Even if they were exhaustive, you would still have to have a default return statement I think.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it won't compile because you don't have an else clause incase none of the cases are correct. Then the method doesn't have a return. Therefore the compiler asks for an int return.

```
public static int f(int a, int b, int c) { 
        if ((a < b) && (b < c))
            return a; 
        else    if ((a >= b) && (b >= c))
            return b;
        else    if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c))
            return c; 
        else{
             System.out.println("No clause matched");
             return 0;  //or something else
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What happen if non of if-else blocks fire ?
you miss the return statement , you can use this way

```
public static int f(int a, int b, int c) {
        int result = 0 ;
        if ((a < b) && (b < c))
            result = a;
        else    if ((a >= b) && (b >= c))
            result = b;
        else    if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c))
            result = c;
        return result;
    }
```

create a return point and among the method's body try to assign a 
corresponding value to this and at the end , return it .

Answer (score 1):

As stated before your function can end without a return.
If this must not happen (one of the condition should always be true) you can also end with an exception:

```
public static int f(int a, int b, int c) throws Exception
{
    if ((a < b) && (b < c))
    {
        return a;
    }
    else if ((a >= b) && (b >= c))
    {
        return b;
    }
    else if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c))
    {
        return c;
    }
    throw new Exception("Input not valid");
}
```

This way the caller can handle the Exception or log that something went wrong.